# How to generate client code using openapi-maven-plugin or swagger-codegen-maven-plugin in kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I need to generate **client's code in kotlin** using **swagger-codegen-maven-plugin or openapi-generator-maven-plugin**. For example in Java I can  set plugin **library** as **resttemplate** and I can autowire generated code. Or I can generate **feign client**. I want to do the same in kotlin, but I don't want to use java-code in kotlin.

I tried different settings for plugins. I could generate java-code and use it in kotlin, but I want  to generate kotlin code only. And I want to use generated code with spring(If generate java code and set library as resttemplate, then generated code is ready to be autowired without additional settings)

Comment: openapi-generator has the [Kotlin client generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators#client-generators). Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't to make what I need